# Left Join With Regular Joins and Results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question with left join. I am trying to LEFT JOIN a table that requires other tables to be joined on the initial left joined table.  So..

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
  ON tableB.id=tableA.id 
JOIN tableC 
  ON tableC.id=tableB.id
```

The problem is if I don't left join table C I get no results, and if do left join I get too many results.

What kind of joins should I be using where if tableB join is null, tableC joins will also be null?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected result based on that data

Comment: Without knowing anything about the table structure, a LEFT JOIN seems like it should be the correct type of join. It's possible that the conditions you're using aren't correct if you think you're getting too many results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a subquery ?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tableB.id FROM tableB
  JOIN tableC 
    ON tableC.id=tableB.id) tableZ
  ON tableZ.id=tableA.id
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't left join table C I get no results, and if do left join I get
>   too many results

You need to determine what is your driving table and data. In this case, it seems like table A is the driving table and the join from B to C also could be a left join, meaning data from C could be returned even if no matching exists in B.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
  ON tableB.id=tableA.id 
LEFT JOIN tableC 
  ON tableC.id=tableB.id
```

> if do left join I get too many results

Can you post some sample data to show what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want this logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN
     (tableB JOIN
      tableC
      ON tableC.id = tableB.id
     )
     ON tableB.id = tableA.id ;
```

Normally, with `LEFT JOIN` you want to chain them, but there are some exceptions.